# Datatables filter based on number value on button click

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have this "filter" for datatables which works great to find a string in a specific column:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#sort_me").click( function()
{
var table = $('#occupations_datatable').DataTable();
table
  .search( '' )
  .columns(0 ).search( 'Architect' )
  .draw();
} );
} );
```

What I'd like to do is instead "search" a different column for all numbers greater than, say, 20. Column 3 in my dataset is all integers and I want someone to be able to click on a button and filter the chart to only show rows where column 3 values are great than a certain number. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#sort_me").click( function()
{
var table = $('#occupations_datatable').DataTable();
table
  .columns(3).filter( function ( value, index ) {
  return value > 20;
})
.draw();
} );
} );
```

I get no errors, but the table doesn't filter itself either. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure the data you're filtering are integers and not strings?

Comment: @isherwood Good questions...they are all INT type in my database. Do I need to do anything else when I call the table to ensure they stay as integers?

Comment: Just to confirm: `Column 3 in my dataset` is actually column 4 because of 0-indexing? Also, have you tried `return parseInt(value) > 20;`

Comment: @Ninsly Correct, it's actually column 4. Adding the 'parseInt' throws an unexpected identifier error.

Comment: @isherwood Of note, if I instead use .search like in my first bit of code and put a number quotes (e.g., "67"), the search works. Does this tell you that the values in that column are strings?

Comment: That's why I asked. I'm not sure what DataTables does with the data. It's been a while since I worked with it.

Comment: Apparently [.filter](http://datatables.net/reference/api/filter%28%29) is not related to re-drawing the table. You might need to create a [custom range search](http://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html).